# Change a string from a function and it's input MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, printf

Basicly my task is the following:
Write a function that has a number and a char as input. It will then open the file
text.txt. The speech should be written in the file with precision 4 and string as the type, i.e. 'e', 'E' etc. The file will then be closed. If the function does not manage to open the file, an error message should appear.

Currently my function looks like this:

```
function [ ] = (a,b)

a=char(a)
fid=fopen('text.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%.4b'l,a);
fclose(fid)

end
```

How can I make my indata "b" change the "b" of the string?

I could really use some help

Sincerely